# How to create the key in an object from data inside an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

How to create the key in an object from data inside an array?

```js
function createIt(data) {
  var obj = {};
  for (i of data) {
    obj["fruit"] = i;
  }
  return [obj];
}

var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list));
```

on my code above, the `obj.fruit` only show the one value,
I want to create something like this:

```
[
  { fruit: "orange" },
  { fruit: "apple" },
  { fruit: "pineapple" }
]
```

Comment: You could use map method `var res = list.map(fruit => ({fruit}))`

Comment: you're overriding `obj["fruit"]`. Add to an array in each iteration instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map the input array and get back an array of objects with the `key` fruit

```js
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(list.map(i => ({ fruit: i })));
```

Here a for loop returning a new array, even if I have no idea why you don't want to use `map` method of arrays:

```js
const list = ["orange", "apple", "banana"];

const newList = [];
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  newList.push({
    fruit: list[i]
  });
}

console.log(newList);
```

Here a for loop changing the input array, even if again, no idea why you can't use `map` method of arrays:

```js
const list = ['orange', 'banana', 'apple'];

for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list.splice(i, 1, {
    fruit: list[i]
  });
}

console.log(list);
```

Back to your original code:

```
function createIt(data){
  var obj = {};
  for(i of data){
    obj["fruit"]= i
  }
  return [obj]
}
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list))
```

You do create a single object, and you always override the value of the `fruit` key. You should create an array, push the objects into the array in the loop, and then return the array, as below:

```js
function createIt(data) {
  var objs = [];
  for (i of data) {
    objs.push({fruit: i});
  }
  return objs;
}
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list))
```

Comment: can we just use for-loop for this case?? :D

Comment: if you want, we can. Do you want to mutate the input list, or do you want to return a new array?

Comment: @ZumDummi Why would you prefer a for loop over a higher order function like `.map()` ?

Comment: can we do both?:D

Comment: @NullDev that's a one million dollar question. Maybe that's an interview and he is just testing us :)

Comment: @ZumDummi I did all the cases I guess. But again, if you are here to learn, in these situations, go for `map` :)

Comment: @ZumDummi Uhm... he was just trying to be helpful and even updated his answer.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your original code, you should define an initial array, rather than an object, and push an object to that array on each iteration:

```js
function createIt(data) {
  const obj = [];
  for (const i of data) {
    obj.push({ fruit: i });
  }
  return obj;
}
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list))
```

That said, `.map` is much more appropriate when creating a new array based on every item from another array.

```js
const createIt = data => data.map(fruit => ({ fruit }));
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need an array. Create the object inside the loop and push the created object to the array in each iteration. Finally return that array:

```js
function createIt(data){
  var arr = [];
  for(i of data){
    var obj = {};
    obj["fruit"]= i;
    arr.push(obj);
  }
  return arr
}
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list))
```

Though you can shorten your code using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
function createIt(data){
  return data.map(d => ({fruit: d}));
}
var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];
console.log(createIt(list))
```

Comment: i like this method:D

Comment: @ZumDummi, great to know that:)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `.map()` to get the desired output:

```js
let list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];

let result = list.map(k => ({fruit: k}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: can we just use for-loop for this case?? :D

Answer (score 0):

**Just push the object into the array and return it!**

```js
'use strict';

function createIt(data) {
  let res = [];

  for (const i of data) {
    res.push({
      fruit: i
    });
  }

  return res;
}

var list = ["orange", "apple", "pineapple"];

console.log(createIt(list));
```

Comment: The code doesn't run in strict mode, but don't forget to define `i` anyway ;)

Comment: @NullDev there fixed it!